# Using swing with libgdx and porting to android

Tags: java, android, swing, android-layout, libgdx

I am looking for ways to avoid remaking my game using android SDK. So I was wondering if it is  possible to use libgdx to edit an android app that uses swing. Then port to android?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to remake your game at some point. I would recommend making it in libgdx and using libgdx for the game UI as well. This way, you'll have an app that'll work on Android, iOS, Desktop, and HTML5.